# Can posterior distribution for a continuous variable be greater than one?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, statistical-inference, bayes-theorem

This might sound a dumb question but I am really confused about it.
According to Bayes' rule we do have the following:
$$p(\theta|X)=\frac{p(\theta)p(X|\theta)}{\int{p(\theta)p(X|\theta)d\theta}}$$

I know that probability density function can be greater than one in general but it seems to me because there exist discrete summations of denominator integral which would is greater than the nominator, therefore posterior probability density function cannot be greater than one in any point. Is this correct?!

To explain reasoning a bit in more detail:

Suppose we are interested in $p(\theta=\theta_0|X)$ and we know that:
$$\int{p(\theta)p(X|\theta)}d\theta\approx\sum\limits_{n}{p(\theta_i)p(X|\theta_i)}$$

but now only consider the summations which include $p(\theta_0)p(\theta_0|X)$. Then the denominator will obviously be larger than the nominator.

Comment: Answered here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74586/can-posterior-distribution-for-a-continuous-variable-be-greater-than-one